# Memory buffers usage in Linux

Tags: linux, memory

I have been looking at the following `free -h` output for a while now and trying to find out what is currently being stored in **-/+ buffers/cache**.

Here is the free output :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G        31G       271M        68K        18M        54M
-/+ buffers/cache:        31G       344M 
Swap:         2.0G       2.0G       1.1M
```

Here is the output of vmstat

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 3  0 2095168 264700  23780  61384    0    0     1     2    0    0  2  0 97  0  0
```

Here is the output of slabtop

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 1245582 / 1349681 (92.3%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 23582 / 23629 (99.8%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 109 / 193 (56.5%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 85297.16K / 95783.38K (89.1%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.02K / 0.07K / 4096.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
633600 633470  99%    0.02K   4400  144     17600K avtab_node
426496 422970  99%    0.03K   3808  112     15232K size-32
   192    192 100%   32.12K    192        1     12288K kmem_cache
 12166   9596  78%    0.55K   1738        7  6952K radix_tree_node
  9468   9455  99%    0.64K   1578        6  6312K proc_inode_cache
 89798  21692  24%    0.06K   1522   59  6088K size-64
 20760  20646  99%    0.19K   1038   20  4152K dentry
  6210   6154  99%    0.58K   1035        6  4140K inode_cache
  1425   1394  97%    2.61K    475        3  3800K task_struct
 15162  13797  90%    0.20K    798   19  3192K vm_area_struct
  3068   2984  97%    1.00K    767        4  3068K size-1024
  2504   2129  85%    0.98K    626        4  2504K ext4_inode_cache
  1172   1096  93%    2.00K    586        2  2344K size-2048
 28143  19300  68%    0.07K    531   53  2124K selinux_inode_security
 13581  13522  99%    0.14K    503   27  2012K sysfs_dir_cache
   427    396  92%    4.00K    427        1  1708K size-4096
  6015   4502  74%    0.25K    401   15  1604K filp
   345    307  88%    2.06K    115        3   920K sighand_cache
  6840   4807  70%    0.12K    228   30   912K size-128
  1648   1204  73%    0.50K    206        8   824K task_xstate
   412    346  83%    1.69K    103        4   824K TCP
  7474   7356  98%    0.10K    202   37   808K buffer_head
  9063   9049  99%    0.07K    171   53   684K Acpi-Operand
  1360   1236  90%    0.50K    170        8   680K size-512
   805    787  97%    0.77K    161        5   644K shmem_inode_cache
 11935  10159  85%    0.05K    155   77   620K anon_vma_chain
   760    636  83%    0.69K    152        5   608K sock_inode_cache
   130    130 100%    4.00K    130        1   520K biovec-256
  2540   2496  98%    0.19K    127   20   508K size-192
   364    307  84%    1.06K     52        7   416K signal_cache
  1515    985  65%    0.25K    101   15   404K skbuff_head_cache
  1380   1086  78%    0.25K     92   15   368K size-256
     5      5 100%   64.00K  5        1   320K size-65536
  7360   7276  98%    0.04K     80   92   320K Acpi-Namespace
  2280   1429  62%    0.12K     76   30   304K pid
   165    104  63%    1.38K     33        5   264K mm_struct
  2244   1409  62%    0.11K     66   34   264K task_delay_info
    16     16 100%   16.00K     16        1   256K size-16384
  1008    552  54%    0.23K     63   16   252K cfq_queue
  5336   4705  88%    0.04K     58   92   232K anon_vma
    55     48  87%    4.00K     55        1   220K names_cache
```

I have been looking at other threads talking about the content of free display but that's not helping. 
Is there any way to list what is actually being store there (files,...)?

Thanks in advance